# guitar tablature question for song

Tags: guitar, tablature

guitar tablature question for song, the imgur is a screen shot of it.
do I hammer onto the 12 then pull off to the 8.
or am i not even close?

[http://imgur.com/5LrBPO1](https://imgur.com/5LrBPO1)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be executed by playing the 5th fret note, right hand hammer on 12th fret, followed by a pull off with the right hand to a fretted 8th fret note.

Comment: I suppose you are right.  I have never considered using the picking hand to hammer on and pull off.  I am not quite sure about the "easily executed"  part but with practice, it can in fact be done.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I might have to incorporate some right hand hammer on's and pull offs into my playing.

Comment: After you made me aware of the possibility of executing a hammer on from the 5th to 12th fret by using both hands on the fretboard, I edited my answer to improve the quality of the content on Stack Exchange.  Thanks for your enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

The symbol pictured which is sometimes referred to as a slur in music notation (curved line that forms an arc connecting two notes) in the image is often used to denote a hammer on in tablature.  A slide is usually indicated by a diagonal line / or \ depending if it's an ascending or descending slide.

But I don't see how you can be playing a note while fretting the string on the 5th fret and then hammer on to the 12th fret **unless you execute the hammer on and pull off with your picking hand as Tim suggests in his answer.**  That is a more advanced technique that is not commonly used -  so I can't discount the possibility that the tab author might be trying to indicate a slide from the 5th fret to the 12th fret and then back to the 8th fret.

If you can listen to a recording of the song, you should be able to determine if the guitarist in the recording is executing a slide or hammer on/pull off.

If that is not possible, you might try contacting the tab author and ask.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a tapping technique using the a finger from the picking hand. You would hammer-on the 12 fret with the right hand finger then pull-off to the 8th fret.

A lot of rock and metal players play like this. Looks like the tab is showing arpeggios with tapping for the 12 fret note.